# Erro ao fazer upload de imagem (cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

Tags: php, apache-cordova, file-upload, cordova-plugin

Estou usando o mesmo código da [documentação](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/file/filetransfer/filetransfer.html#upload), porém quando envio para o PHP, não aparece nenhum arquivo.

**JS**

```
function uploadPhotoRevendedor(imageURI) {
    var success = function (r) {
        app.alert("Code = " + r.responseCode + "Response = " + r.response + "Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }
    var fail = function (error) {
        app.alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code + "Source = " + error.source + "Target = " + error.target);
    }
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

    // Upload image
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(...'model/foto-revendedor.php'), success, fail, options);
}
```

**PHP**

```
print_r(json_encode($_FILES));
$new_image_name = urldecode($_FILES["file"]["name"]).".jpg";
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../users/".$new_image_name);
```

O http code retorna 200 OK na função success mas o $_FILES aparece vazio...

[image: request]

Comment: Está dando erro?

Comment: Então retorna como 200 - OK o 'responseCode', mas não sei pq no php $_FILES fica vazia...

Comment: Ja deu um `console.log(imageURI)` ? para ver se está certo?

Comment: Sim aparece o mesmo da foto do request ali em Request URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após tentar várias soluções e nada funcionar, resolvi remover os **plugins do cordova** e adicionar novamente, não sei exatamente o motivo mas finalmente funcionou!

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-file-transfer

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```